# get the parameter from the url which has slace in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

My URL is like below

```
http://localhost/demo/company/warehouse_subportal/printEway/CN/00003
```

my invoice no is CN/00003 and sometimes CN-00003.
 what I want is to get the invoice from URL. Now I am getting only CN.I know that is because of /. How can I get the invoice no like CN/00003? Please help me thanks in Advance.

Comment: URL encode your URL: `/printEway/CN%2F00003`

Comment: please can you share any example.I will follow that.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.urlencode.php), when you generate your links or urls example:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

and then use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.urldecode.php) to decode the invoice value, example:

```
<?php
$query = "my=apples&are=green+and+red";

foreach (explode('&', $query) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk);

    if ($param) {
        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
    }
}
?>
```

Note, that only the invoice part needs to be encoded or decoded, the part of

> CN/00003

another possible solution is to encode into [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.base64-encode.php), example:

```
<?php
$str = 'This is an encoded string';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

and decode it using [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.base64-decode.php), example:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for everyone.Now base64_encode() and base64_decode() fixed my issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data='http://localhost/demo/company/warehouse_subportal/printEway/CN-00003';

$data=explode('/',$data);

if(is_numeric(array_values(array_slice($data, -1))[0])){
    $invoice=implode(array_slice($data, -2, 2, true),'/');

}
else{
    $invoice=array_values(array_slice($data, -1))[0];
}

echo $invoice;
```

So basically i check the last field of the url to see if it contains only numbers or has also letters and based on the response i echo the right value.

Works for both / and -

Comment: The URL can also be `/CN-00003` as mentioned in the question, in which case this would not work :)

Comment: for example if my invoice no like this CN-00003 how it will work

Comment: sometimes my invoice does not have special character like this 10001001

Comment: And what does it have? So the last field can be what? 10001001  these are digits not special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segments.

```
if(strpos($this->uri->segment(4), '-') !== FALSE){
   $invoice_num = $this->uri->segment(4);
}
else {
   $invoice_num = $this->uri->segment(4).'/'.$this->uri->segment(5);
}
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

Comment: if invoice does not have slash or iphon

Answer (score 0):

Encode & Decode the parameter will resolve your issue.

Exemple:

When preparing the url:

```
$invoice_number = urlencode("CN/00003") // Or "CN-00003"

$url = "http://localhost/demo/company/warehouse_subportal/printEway/" . $invoice_number
```

To get the invoice number from url:

```
$invoice_number = urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));
```